# Jenkins jobs fails with error "The batch file cannot be found. Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure"

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have batch script calling some python files configured in Jenkins jobs as below:

'''python script.py --commandline_parameter1 value1'''

If the script.py execute for longer time, sometimes I am seeing an error as mentioned below while the script execution is successful and I am getting the expected output also. But only the Jenkins job status will be Failure.

*The batch file cannot be found.
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE*

The Job is Success when the script runs for shorter time without any failure.

Why is it happening? And what can be the fix for this ?

I can't put a exit 0 as I actually need to know if there is an actual failure in the script also.

Regards
Sreevalsa

Answer (score -1):

you can use %errorlevel% to fail the Jenkns job if script.py failed.
See the batch script below:

```
'''
python script.py --commandline_parameter1 value1 
exit %ERRORLEVEL% 
'''
```

Comment: My problem is even when script is not failing jenkins job is getting failed if the script was executed for very long time.